# Angular tabs with filter not working

Tags: angularjs

Trying to build angular tabs using bootstrap tabs and filter the content according to the category mentioned in the object data. And the Controller function includes javascript object with properties.
I don't know where I went wrong?
Below is my code:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 

</head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
         <div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                   <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSelected(1)}">
                <a
                 aria-controls="all"
                 role="tab" ng-click="ctrl.select(1)">All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSelected(2)}">
                <a
                 aria-controls="ui"
                 role="tab" ng-click="ctrl.select(2)">UI</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSelected(3)}">
                <a
                 aria-controls="backend"
                 role="tab" ng-click="ctrl.select(3)">Backend</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:ctrl.isSelected(4)}">
                <a
                 aria-controls="student"
                 role="tab" ng-click="ctrl.select(4)">Student</a></li>
            </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <li ng-repeat="dish in ctrl.dishes | filter:Ctrl.filtText">{{ dish.name + ', ' + dish.age + ', ' + dish.category +', ' +dish.job }}</li>
       </ul>


     </div>
   </div>
   <script>
      var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
      app.controller('myCtrl',function(){
        this.filtText = '';
        this.tab=1;

       var dishes=[
          {
            name:'mit',
           age:'23',
           category:'Ui',
            job:'UI Developer'

         },
        {
            name:'Manu',
           age:'30',
           category:'backend',
            job:'SE'

           },
          {
          name:'Emily',
          age:'21',
          category:'student',
          job:'SE'

         },
          {
             name:'Ben',
             age:'27',
             category:'business',
              job:'UI Developer'

            }

          ];

        this.dishes = dishes;
        this.select = function(setTab) {
            this.tab = setTab;

            if (setTab === 2)
                this.filtText = "Ui";
            else if (setTab === 3)
                this.filtText = "backend";
            else if (setTab === 4)
                this.filtText = "student";
            else
                this.filtText = "";

        }
         this.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return (this.tab === checkTab);
        }

      });

      </script>

       </body>
```

Comment: can u add `select` and `isSelected` code snippets

Comment: it's there inside controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are filtering based on `category` so 
update`ng-repeat` as following

**Note**: make sure `ctrl` is in lowercase. its case sensitive

```
  <div class="tab-content">
    <ul class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <li ng-repeat="dish in ctrl.dishes | filter: {category: ctrl.filtText}">{{ dish.name + ', ' + dish.age + ', ' + dish.category +', ' +dish.job }}</li>
   </ul>

 </div>
```